# Show $ \sum_f \lambda(f)t^{\deg f} = \prod_g \big(1 - \lambda(g)t^{\deg g}\big)^{-1} $

Tags: calculus, number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, geometric-series

So I want to  show that $$ \sum_f \lambda(f)t^{\deg f} = \prod_g \big(1 - \lambda(g)t^{\deg g}\big)^{-1} $$ where the sum is over monic polynomials and the product is over all monic irreducible polynomials in $F[x]$, where $F$ is a finite field.

Proof : So I know that this identity is proved by expanding each term $\big(1-\lambda(g)t^{\deg g }\big)^{-1}$ in a geometric series and using the fact that every monic polynomial can be written as a product of monic irreducible polynomials in a unique way. As you can see the details are left. Can you give me a complete proof?

So first expanding $\big(1-\lambda(g)t^{\deg g }\big)^{-1} $. We get $\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \big(\lambda(g)t^{\deg g}\big)^r$. Now I have 
to show $$\displaystyle \sum_f \lambda(f)t^{\deg f} =\prod_g \left(\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \big(\lambda(g)t^{\deg g}\big)^r\right)\,.$$  I only have to use the fact above. But how exactly? ***Attention definition of $\lambda$ :*** For a monic polynom $f(x) =
x^n - c_1x^{n-1} + \cdots + (-1)^nc_n$ in $F[x]$ we define $\lambda(f) = \psi(c_1)\chi(c_n)$, where $\psi$ is a character with additive structure and $\chi$ is a multiplicative character. Moreover you should know that $\lambda$ is multiplicative. So $\lambda(fg) = \lambda(f) \lambda(g)$.

Comment: What is $\lambda(f)$?

Comment: And what is $F$? An arbitrary field?

Comment: It can only makle sense if $\lambda(f) = 0$ for all but finitely many $f$ of a fixed degree.

Comment: I am sorry that I haven't said what $F$ and $\lambda(f)$ are. $F$ is a finite field. $\lambda(f)$ is $\psi(c_1)\chi(c_d)$ for $f = x^d - c_1x^{d-1} + ... + (-1)^dc_d$. Moreover $\psi$ and $\chi $ are characters. I dont think that this is important but $\psi$ has "additive" structure and $\chi$ has "multiplicative" structure.

Comment: Your claim is true iff $\lambda$ is completely multiplicative (on monic polynomials). This is exactly the same as the Euler product of the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: Dear @reuns ,  You are right $\lambda$ is multiplicative. I  have edited this information last week. I have really tried to proof this claim, but I failed. I hope that I don't annoy you, but can you please give me the details with an answer?

Comment: Look at a proof of the Euler product for the Riemann zeta function. Here it is exactly the same for $$\prod_{g \in F[x]_{monic}, g \text{irreducible}} (1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda(g^k)t^{\deg(g^k)}) = \sum_{f \in F[x]_{monic}} \lambda(f) t^{\deg(f)} $$ using the unique factorization in $F[x]_{monic}$